# sys.stdout.write no longer prints on next row

Tags: python, printing

So I have this piece of code, very basic stuff that I'm working on. I stumbled upon this "slow type" thing, that I like but if I use it instead of all print functions, most of my output is written on one row.

```
import sys, time


def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.02)

print_slow('What\'s your name?')

name = raw_input()

print_slow('My name is ' + name)

if name == 'alex' or name == 'Alex':
    print_slow('That\'s a good name')
if name == 'Alexandru' or name == 'alexandru':
    print_slow('That\'s a very good name')
```

Comment: Add `sys.stdout.write('\n')` to the end of your function definition (after the end of the `for` loop).

Comment: This writes every letter on a new row.

Comment: This worked. I added it inside the loop at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print a newline character (`\n`) at the end of each line where you so desire, or add it to the `print_slow` function.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would add it to the print_slow function. Because it would be too much to add it after every single line.

Comment: you would add a new line at the end of the function definition outside of the for loop: `sys.stdout.write('\n')`