# Printing in the Different Line in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the following code in different lines but it always prints in the same line. Can anyone help please.

```
import time
import sys


def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)


delay_print("Hi there hope everything is fine.")
time.sleep(2)


def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)


delay_print("This is a mail.")
```

This is the output showing to me-

```
Hi there hope everything is fine.This is a mail.
```

How to print them like this-

```
Hi there hope everything is fine.
This is a mail.
```

Comment: Add `print()` at the end of `delay_print()` to print a newline.

Comment: You can find a similar question with answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/45149908/12451425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can put `\n` just in argument to function but better put it in function itself

```
def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)
    print("\n")
```

Also, **on a side note,** you dont need to re decalre the `delay_print` function

You can do the same thing as below without defining a function two times

```
import time
import sys


def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        ime.sleep(0.05)
    print("\n")

delay_print("Hi there hope everything is fine.")
time.sleep(2)
delay_print("This is a mail.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `print("\n")` after the for loop.

Functions are written when a particular task is to be done multiple times, declaring the same function is not needed just call it, and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You either want to use `sys.stdout.writelines()`, where you would pass a list of 1 value to, or you want to add in `your delay_print()` an end-of-line token as `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

Just add `\n` at the end of string in first `delay_print()` :

```
import time
import sys

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)

delay_print("Hi there hope everything is fine.\n") # like this .
time.sleep(2)
delay_print("This is a mail.")
```